# How do vassals make money?

Tags: oh-edo-towns

As you play the game, it's explained that farmers work at Fields, merchants and artisans work at a Wholesaler, and warriors can work at either Fields or Castles.

Vassals, however, are never really explained. Where do vassals go to earn income?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vassals can do whatever they want. They can work at the fields, at the wholesaler, and at the castles.